# Best practice: looking for integration test framework for AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webdriver-io

I need to have some integration tests over my AWS Lambda function, and I need to know which framework is the best practice for this scenario.

For sure it can be also used for node.js but if the framework is more applicable for lambda so it's better.

Currently I found some info about `webdriver.io` and I wonder to know if it's good enough for my needs.

Please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Lambda functions are exposed via API Gateway since you mentioned using `webdriver-io`. For testing your API Gateway API I recommend [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), although webdriver/Selenium is another good testing tool.

For testing and deploying individual NodeJS Lambda functions, if you aren't using a larger framework like [Serverless](https://serverless.com/), then I recommend [the Apex framework](http://apex.run/). For local testing of NodeJS Lambda functions I recommend [the lambda-local module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local).

Comment: serverless suits for integration tests also ?

Comment: I don't use the serverless framework, so I'm not entirely sure, but it definitely appears to provide some testing functionality. Are you using the serverless framework already?

Comment: yet, I'm just looking to find the best practice

Comment: "Best" is entirely relative. There are several equally good ways of doing this. If you focus on asking for the single "best" way of doing something your questions on this site will tend to be closed as off-topic due to the opinionated nature of any response.